# Makin a Shared Library optional

Tags: android, gradle, option-type, barcode-scanner

I am programming scanners and I want to use the same app for two models.
- The first one uses a **shared library** which is only available on the first model (Zebra device). 
- The second one should use the **camera only and is no Zebra device**.

When trying to install the apk on non-Zebra device is **INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY**

My build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    // Play Services for Barcode API
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:9.4.0+'

    // Misc
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

    // Zebra EMDK
    provided fileTree(include: ['com.symbol.emdk.jar'], dir: 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk\\add-ons\\addon-symbol_emdk-symbol-19\\libs')
    compile fileTree(exclude: ['com.symbol.emdk.jar'], dir: 'libs')
}
```

In my manifest I have `<uses-permission android:name="com.symbol.emdk.permission.EMDK" />`

I tried the nebula plugin (https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-extra-configurations-plugin) and make the two Zebra-entries in my build.gradle "optional" but I still cannot install the apk.
How can I make the Zebra library optional? 
Thank you a lot for any tips!

Comment: by making two product flavors...

Comment: the rest of the app is completely equal and I would like to make it in one app if possible.

Answer (score 2):

As Christian says, you need to specify `<uses-library android:name="com.symbol.emdk" android:required="false"/>`.  You will also need to detect which type of device your app is running on.  I have a similar app that uses EMDK and works on both Zebra and non-Zebra devices: https://github.com/darryncampbell/WakeLock_WifiLock_Exerciser.  Please take a look at that if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Easily fixed by setting `<uses-library android:name="com.symbol.emdk" android:required="false"/>` instead of `<uses-permission android:name="com.symbol.emdk.permission.EMDK" />` in manifest and using nebula.